# GUI restarts after wake up from suspend or boot ('Application 'compiz.desktop' killed ..)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, gnome, nvidia, compiz

I am facing a crash almost each time I boot my computer and sometimes that I wake it from suspend.

I've looked at the logs, and what seems to appear as a *critical* error is this:

> May 21 21:25:22 desktop gnome-session[2870]: WARNING: Application
>   'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 11
>   May 21 21:25:22 gnome-session[2870]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too
>   quickly
>   May 21 21:25:22 desktop gnome-session[2870]: CRITICAL: We
>   failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

I have an Nvidia graphics card and I am currently using the nouveau driver (was using the latest one from nvidia, but changed it in order to see if this changes anything, **it's not**).

**Crash description:**

**1. When**
The problem started occurring in the last month.

**2. Where**
This is how my **login screen** looks sometimes
[image: crashed-login-screen]
 [image: crashed-login-screen-topbar]

When I type my password, some distorted tiles of the screen appear of-place, for example, a tile displaying the folders *that normally appear at the left bottom of the screen* now appear at the top right screen (**that tile**, there's no rearranging issue, it actually crashes).

**Additional drivers**
These are the additional drivers, that currently appear:
[image: additional-drivers-screenshot]
Which driver should I be using? How can I remove them all and re-install only one?

*System Description*
Ubuntu 14.04.2 - 64bit, Unity3D DE
nVidia GTX 280
Using a two monitors setup